# Sunsetting Microsoft Identity Management for Unix the right way

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, unix, identity-management

I'd like to make sure that we don't have any connections to our AD controllers before sunsetting, but some run Microsoft Identity Management for Unix / Server for NIS. I'm having a dog of a time trying to find any related logging for this service though, and not seeing it in the Event Viewer. Does it log specific events (i.e., events that set it apart from normal AD logons) in the Security log? Or is there a separate log somewhere?